# The aerial building model of the unmanned aerial vehicle, if the right angle is calculated quickly, thereby reducing the number of surfaces

Tags: python

Here is a model that cannot be photographed by humans, with many vertices and triangular faces. But, as you know, most building profiles are mostly right angles. Are there any plugins, scripts or good ways to effectively reduce redundant faces? In particular, the main structure of the building is preserved.

[image]

[image]

PS:The following is the effect of manual modeling and then mapping.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, this effectively reduces the number of faces and conforms to the structure of the building. However, the disadvantage is that it takes a lot of time to model. Excuse me, is there any plugin, script or any good way to improve efficiency that can be processed quickly.

Comment: You can try blendergis and blender osm https://prochitecture.gumroad.com/l/blender-osm https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS

Comment: The architecture of OSMGIS is very nice. But unfortunately, he does not have it everywhere, and the buildings in many places do not match the actual situation. Also, sadly, the textures don't match either.